# Regarding the stability of sub-Chandrasekhar limit neutronium and state evolution. (a second sun?)

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, neutron-stars

Suppose we have an isolated Neutron star just above the Chandrasekhar limit, and we managed to pull enough neutrons out to lower below a stable mass limit.

Qualitatively, I imagine some some neutron cloud probability density inversely proportional to radius from it's surface, which, at some point has a finite probability of free neutron decay.

Considering the high local gravity and small radius of such an object, I imagine that, for the most part, only the neutrinos and gamma rays would completely escape the local gravity. This kind of makes me think the whole system would slowly evolve towards a hydrogen cloud (first forming as an orbit around it) (which itself might eventually begin to fuse to other elements?)
It almost appears like there's a potential to reboot an entire stellar process (albeit unnaturally).

Note it would seem the smaller the mass of the neutronium piece the faster the rate of decay (somewhat reminiscent of black hole radiation)

Does anyone know what really happens, QFT answers and quantitative answers are great (if possible)!

Comment: According to Ethan Siegel, the smallest possible neutron star is
 [200 meters in radius --- enough matter to be comparable to about the mass of Saturn, and that’s the lower-limit of what you’d need. Anything less massive, and your ball of neutrons will decay.](https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/ask-ethan-79-the-tiniest-neutron-star-e5808e8fa328) (He gives no source.) I don't think this has anything to do with the Chandrasekhar limit.

Comment: @KeithMcClary     Thank you for the reference, it's the decay process that I'm ultimately interested in, especially the decay rate  Would it be a usable energy source over time, or some runaway reaction (certainly the latter for small masses i imagine)

Comment: Ah! I'm just reading now that this is exactly how gold and a lot of heavier elements are formed!